# Script that compares 2 file's sizes and gives a warning message

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script, bash-scripting

I am a complete noob in scripting, but I need a script that will compare the sizes of two files and give out a warning if one of those files is 10% bigger than the other.

So far, I came up with this :

```
#!/bin/bash
test1=/trans/home/user/test1
test2=/trans/home/user/test2
test1=$(stat -c%s "$test1")
test2=$(stat -c%s "$test2")

if (( test2 > 110 * test1 ))
then
  echo "WARNING: test2 has increased 10% or more in size"
fi
```

I created two files with touch and tinkered their sizes with truncate. No matter what sizes I give them, this will not give the warning message,UNless I switch the greater than to < sign, then it gives the warning message. 
However this doesn't work for me.

Any ideas how to edit this to work will be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math isn't correct. Below is a script that use `bc` precision calculator that can do floating point operation without worrying of overflow in `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

test1=/trans/home/user/test1
test2=/trans/home/user/test2
test1sz=$(stat -c%s "$test1")
test2sz=$(stat -c%s "$test2")

[ $(echo "scale=2; ${test2sz} > ${test1sz}*1.1" | bc) -eq 1 ] && {
  echo "WARNING: ${test2} has increased 10% or more in size"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need

```
if (( test2 > 110 * test1 / 100))
```

size plus 10% is 1.10 or 110/100, not 110. Note that you should first multiply and then divide, otherwise 110/100 rounded to an integer is just 1.00. On the other hand, 110*test1 may exceed the integer range, anthough that is not likely with file sizes and 64-bit integers.

Comment: In this case multiplying by 11 and then dividing by 10 would reduce the risk of overflowing. `test1 / 10 + test1` may be even better.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That is true, but as I mentioned, the risk of overflowing 64 bits with a file size is low, and easy understandable code also has its value.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
test1=/trans/home/stefan01/test1
test2=/trans/home/stefan01/test2
test1=$(stat -c%s "$test1")
test2=$(stat -c%s "$test2")
PERC=$(bc <<< "scale=2; ($test2 - $test1)/$test1 * 100")
echo "$PERC %"
```

This shows the exact filesize difference in percentages. I can now simply if/then for it to also display a warning message if the result is 10% or more.

Thank you for your help guys.